# Mysql query that searches in table with no reference to current search?

Tags: mysql

I have a HTML input field that **searches for names** in a MySql table and drops down a DIV that displays first 15 records found.

The names are displayed with `DISTINCT` (so unique values).

If I type in for example `adr` in the text input box, it will display first 15 matches for "%adr%".

What I need to do now (and I can't get any luck with it), is look for 2 different types of codes (located in `codes_table_1` and `codes_table_2`), in the same text input field (so expanding my existing query).

The structure of the 2 `codes_tables` would be this below (each having id and name as columns):

```
code_id_1 | code_name_1
    1          XK112932
    2          XK082192
    3            ...
```

and

```
code_id_2 | code_name_2
    1          GG882931
    2          GG014253
    3            ...
```

So I need to find a way to add to my DISTINCT rows containing unique persons with their phone and addresses, these codes, as in adding new rows to the result query.

For example if instead of a name I look for **"KD139"**, I need to get 1st 15 occurences that begin / or have inside the code KD139, looking this up into the 2 codes tables.

Here's my query for unique names :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.last_name,''), ' ',
                             COALESCE(customer.first_name,'')) as fullName, 
                                    customer.first_name, 
                                    customer.last_name, 
                                    customer.email, 
                                    address.phone, 
                                    customer.customer_id

                            FROM customer

                            LEFT JOIN address
                            ON address.address_id = customer.address_id



                            WHERE CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.first_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.last_name,'')) LIKE :search OR 
                                  CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.last_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.first_name,'')) LIKE :search OR 
                                    customer.business_name LIKE :search OR 
                                    customer.email LIKE :search OR 
                                    address.phone LIKE :search

                            LIMIT 15
```

### UPDATE (a solution that works!) :

```
(SELECT DISTINCT 
    customer.customer_id,
    CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.last_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.first_name,'')) as fullName,
    customer.email, 
    address.phone

FROM customer

LEFT JOIN address
ON address.address_id = customer.address_id

INNER JOIN th_table

WHERE CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.first_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.last_name,'')) LIKE :search OR 
      CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.last_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.first_name,'')) LIKE :search OR 
      customer.business_name LIKE :search OR 
      customer.email LIKE :search OR 
      address.phone LIKE :search 

ORDER BY fullName ASC

LIMIT 15)

UNION ALL

(SELECT code1_table.code1_id, 
    code1_table.code1_number, 
    'TH_TABLE' as email, 
    Null as phone

FROM code1_table

WHERE code1_table.code1_number LIKE :search

ORDER BY code1_table.code1_number ASC

LIMIT 15)

UNION ALL

(SELECT code2_table.code2_id, 
    code2_table.code2_number, 
    'CODE2_TABLE' as email, 
    Null as phone

FROM code2_table

WHERE code2_table.code2_number LIKE :search

ORDER BY code2_table.code2_number ASC

LIMIT 15)
```

Comment: `UNION` rather than `JOIN` is a way of solving the problem of looking in multiple places for a single search term.

Comment: i have tried using UNION using 2 SELECT a.* FROM t LIMIT 15 with UNION in the middle, but it says that the number of columns differ and are of different types...can you be more specific ? I haven't used UNION so far...

Comment: so basically the UNION between 2 SELECT queries, where 1st SELECT has 5 fields, and the 2nd SELECT has only 2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to search `artist` and `song` tables together for search terms. You might try someting like this.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM (
            SELECT 'artist' as type, 
                   first as first, last as last, label as tag
              FROM artist 
             WHERE first LIKE '%searchterm%'
                OR last LIKE '%searchterm%'
                OR label LIKE '%searchterm%'
           UNION ALL
            SELECT 'song' as type, 
                   title as first, '' as last, '' as tag
              FROM song
             WHERE title LIKE '%searchterm%'
       )
```

This gets you a result set with information from both tables in it, formatted so `UNION ALL` makes sense. You can then filter and order the results appropriately for your application.

I offer only one guarantee on this sample code: It **will** be slow. `LIKE '%thing'` is a notorious performance antipattern.

Comment: I managed to work out the solution before your answer, based on another StackOverflow post that was exactly what I need, but thank you! As a future reference for my code, how can you replace LIKE %search% ? Is there any other way to search a substring in a VARCHAR ?

Comment: There's `FULLTEXT` search, which is built for your kind of application.

Comment: I wasn't aware that MySql has FULLTEXT search...I knew that they only have text search in VARCHAR fields....